# Prisma 2 with different databases

Tags: prisma2

I'm new at prisma 2 but have got a database working. I have used prisma 'init' and 'migrate dev' to create database tables for my model and can interact with the database using the Prisma client - prisma 2.22.1

Usually for a project, I'd have dev, test and prod environments and use env-cmd to set the relevant differences, e.g. connection details for getting to the database.

With prisma 2 however, it seems like there's a single .env file that is used for the database connection details, so I cannot see how to proceed for the different environments.

Note that I'm not meaning different types of database - in this example all are postgresql.

I can see possibilities for getting past this hurdle, for example for the script to write a suitable .env file according to the required environment as part of running the app, but 'not ideal' really doesn't give this idea the review that it deserves. Or getting more computers.

Any suggestions please for using different databases from the same project? Am I missing something basic or is it deliberately blocked?